# "using" (typedef) pointer : its default constructor return nullptr?

Tags: c++, pointers, using

Does the default constructor of pointer that is lightly encapsulated by `using` always return a `nullptr`?

In other words, does this function always return nullptr?

```
using GOID  = Go_id*;  //some outer scope
GOID f(){
    return GOID(); //always nullptr?
}
```

I tested it many times; it is always `nullptr`.

However, I am not sure whether I am lucky, or it is the C++ specification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is [value initialisation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization) and yes, given the pointer type, it will always be zero in this case. Quoting from the link;

> The effects of value initialization are:
>
> ... [redacted as not pertaining to the case of the pointer type] ...
>
> 4) otherwise, the object is zero-initialized

Comment: Thank for the link to the specification!  That is what I have been searching for.

Comment: @javaLover Note that cppreference isn't the specification, although it's usually pretty accurate.

Comment: @javaLover. I find that site is very useful - and generally easier to absorb that the full spec.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, according to the C++ standard using expression T() where T is a pointer type returns null pointer.

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with typedefs.

Value-initializing (i.e. `T()`) for pointer types performs zero-initialization. `GOID` is a pointer type, so you get zero.